# Import Custom JAR inside MIRTH. (2.2.1.5861)

Tags: javascript, java, mule, mirth

I am using MIRTH to call to external API endpoint which is https. Since MIRTH doesn't inherently has capability to call to https, it throws ssl exception.
I created a jar which will allow localhost to bypass ssl checking. Now I put that jar inside MirthConenct->custom-lib folder. Below is my jar's structure.

```
package Mirth.ssl;
public class TrustSSLCerts{
   ............. }
```

from Transformer's javascript writer I do

```
importPackage(Packages.Mirth.ssl.*);

foo() {
  var ssl = new TrustSSLCerts();
 }
```

On deploying channel and sending dummy data, it errors out-:

**ReferenceError: "TrustSSLCerts" is not defined.**

I am running MIRTH (2.2.1.5861). Any help regarding that is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I need to call the class explicitly. I had to do below in order to have it working-:

```
var ssl = Packages.Mirth.ssl.TrustSSLCerts();
```

instead of

```
var ssl = TrustSSLCerts();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the Mirth Service, since new JARs are only read at the initial start.

Comment: Not necessarily. This can be done by simple "Refresh" in Settings -> Resources. (in the latest 3.x version, not sure about Mirth 2.x).